# WebDriver > context menu webdriver 2.42 and Firefox v31

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

i had firefox 23 and webdriver 2.35 and following code to click context menu was working fine, but i recently upgraded firefox to version 31 and webdriver to 2.42, and i am not able to click on the context menu

```
public static void clickTreeMenuItem(String treeNodeText, String menuItemText){

    rightClickTreeNode(treeNodeText);
    contextClick(menuItemText);
}


public static void rightClickTreeNode(String nodeText){


    List<WebElement> treeNodes = driver.findElements(By.className("class-name"));
    for(WebElement treeNode : treeNodes){
        if(treeNode.getText().equals(nodeText)){

            Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
            Action rightClick = builder.contextClick(treeNode).build();
            rightClick.perform();

        }
    }
}

public static void contextClick(String menuItem){

    waitFor(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.className("x-menu-list-item")));
    List<WebElement> allMenuItems = driver.findElements(By.className("x-menu-list-item"));

    for(WebElement item : allMenuItems){
        if(item.getText().equals(menuItem)){
            item.click();
            break;
        }
    }       
}
```

HTML source of context menu

```
 <div class=" x-menu-list" style="height: 72px;">
    <div id="x-menu-el-xx" class="x-menu-list-item ">
        <span id="com.xx" class=" x-menu-item x-unselectable x-component" unselectable="on" style="color: black;">
            New Item
        </span>
    </div>
```

current behavior : i see right click happening and see the context menu, but the click is not happening. and i dont see any related exceptions, webdriver is just moving to next step..any pointers..?

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved when i used 'x-menu-item' instead of using 'x-menu-list-item'

```
public static void contextClick(String menuItem){

waitFor(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.className("x-menu-item")));
List<WebElement> allMenuItems = driver.findElements(By.className("x-menu-item"));

for(WebElement item : allMenuItems){
    if(item.getText().equals(menuItem)){
        item.click();
        break;
    }
}       
}
```